# Printing Full Workflow History

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow, workflow-history, status

On the workflow status page of all workflows for a custom workflow, the number of items in the workflow history extends beyond 50 items.  This means they are not visible on the status page.

How can I print the full workflow history without having to navigate to the second page of history items?

Comment: Maybe go to the Workflow History list, sort by date, and filter by the desired workflow?

Comment: @PirateEric Tried that but it is more cumbersome than clicking through the pages and printing each page for end-users.  Is there a way to remove the 50 item limit on the workflow status page for workflow history section?

Comment: Not that I know of. I created a simple view of UserID, Date Occurred, Outcome, and Description on the workflow history list and then just filtered by the appropriate list item id. looks and prints ok. How often do you need to do this?